# GitHub Page Custom URL Styling and Pics don't render

Tags: css, url, jekyll, github-pages, blogs

My site, Jekyll static pages and a blog, https://omnebonum.github.io/dsu/ on GitHub pages looks like it is supposed to (such as it is). I have a custom URL set up that points the repo to democracystraightup.org. That works but when I go that URL the pages show up without any CSS or pics.

I know this isn't super specific information, but you can check them both out if you like, and any general insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All your css, javascript and other assets are returning 404 errors:

[image: 404 errors]

The paths are all pointing to subdirectories of `http://democracystraightup.org/dsu/` (e.g. `http://democracystraightup.org/dsu/js/gallery.js`).

Thats wrong.

You need to drop the `/dsu` to make it work.

For example `http://democracystraightup.org/js/gallery.js` works totally fine.